# C++ tools with the same functionality as Python's filter and map

Tags: python, c++, boost, functional-programming

I am looking for a C++ analogs for a `map` or `filter` from Python programming language. The first of them applies some *function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results*, the second *constructs a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true*.

I would like to use the similar functionality in C++:

- Map some function to the container in order to get new container with a transformed data (and probably with a different length);
- Use some kind of conditional filtering for a container;

Are there any fine implementations of Python's map and filter in C++?

In this short example I am trying to work it out using such tools as `boost::bind` and `std::for_each` and I face with a difficulties. The `std::vector<std::string> result` should contain all the strings `std::vector<std::string> raw` that lexicographicaly higher than the last string from stdin. But in fact the `result` container is still empty at the return point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void filter_strings(std::string& current, std::string& last, std::vector<std::string>& results)
{
    if (current > last)
    {
        results.push_back(current);
        std::cout << "Matched: " << current << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> raw, result;
    std::string input, last;

    //Populate first container with a data
    while(std::getline(std::cin, input))
        raw.push_back(input);
    last = raw.back();

    //Put into result vector all strings which lexicographically higher than the last one
    std::for_each(raw.begin(), raw.end(), boost::bind(&filter_strings, _1, last, result));

    //For some reason the resulting container is empty
    std::cout << "Results: " << result.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The input and the output:

```
[vitaly@thermaltake 1]$ ./9_boost_bind 
121
123
122
120                      //Ctrl+D key press
Matched: 121
Matched: 123
Matched: 122
Results: 0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: you will need to write some pretty nasty templates for good generic `map` and `filter` function that work on std container, I tried it once and failed. Instead you should use `std::algorithm` as @juanchopanza suggest.

Comment: take a look at boost range, it's lead to code quite similar to linq and python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @juanchopanza has suggested, the template functions in the `<algorithm>` STL header are your best bet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::string> filter(std::vector<std::string> & raw) {
    std::vector<std::string> result(raw.size());
    std::string last = raw[raw.size() - 1];
    auto it = std::copy_if(raw.begin(), raw.end(), result.begin(),
        [&](std::string s) { return s.compare(last) > 0; });
    result.resize(std::distance(result.begin(), it));
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> raw, result;
    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        raw.push_back(input);
    }

    result = filter(raw);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Matched: " << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Results: " << result.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -o cppfilter main.cpp && ./cppfilter
121
123
122
120  // Ctrl + D pressed
Matched: 121
Matched: 123
Matched: 122
Results: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code is not working as you thought it would is that `bind()` makes a copy of all the parameters. That means that you were adding items to a copy of your `std::vector<string> result;`
To resolve this issue you need to put your vector into a reference wrapper. That then gets copied but it contains a reference to your `result` vector. The change is small:

```
std::for_each(raw.begin(), raw.end(), std::bind(&filter_strings, std::placeholders::_1, last, std::ref(result)));
```

Note that I'm using the C++11 bind, not boost bind here.

Now if you want to use a lambda to keep the predicate code local to the filter you could:

```
std::for_each(raw.begin(), raw.end(), [&](std::string& s){ if (s > last) result.push_back(s); });
```

Or using `std::copy_if`:

```
std::copy_if(raw.begin(), raw.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&](std::string& s){ return s > last; });
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your current code work, you have to wrap the `result` argument to `boost::bind` inside `boost::ref()`, otherwise `bind` will make a copy of your result.

Otherwise, the commenters @juanchopanza and @alexbuisson already gave good answers on this.

Using the plain C++11 standard library (i.e. without Boost), you could implement your above program by replacing the `std::for_each()` with the following (note that the `filter_strings` function is not needed anymore and you neeed to `#include <iterator>` for `std::back_inserter`):

```
std::copy_if(raw.begin(), raw.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [&](std::string const& current) -> bool {
        if (current > last)
        {
            std::cout << "Matched: " << current << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Although this is (probably, if you know the STL) better than your initial approach with custom `push_back` in `for_each` it still does not look very nice. Generally, more readable code can be written using Boost.Range, where you can find nearly 1:1 replacements for `map` and `filter`: [`filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) and [`transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html). For the program above, these would not be particularly helpful, but especially for chained map/filter, using Boost.Range tends to help.